# which the best for build shape in my web page clip-path, svg or canvas

Tags: html, css

i confused between clip-path or svg or canvas to make shape in my page,
which is the best for it ,and why?

Comment: Please restrain from opinion-based questions.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The clip-path CSS property creates a clipping region that sets what part of an element should be shown.

So between SVG and Canvas, for a shape, I would go with SVG, since it's scalable and you don't have problems with blurry images on zoom and device pixel density.

Comment: but i can make shape by clip-patth prop without  svg, and i think for hardware it's better than make id by svg to build one shape

Comment: if you are thinking about "optimization", the way you choose to create this shape really doesn't matter. I would care much more about the cross-browser compatibility. Be careful if you go with clip-path, because things like geometry-box such as fill-box and stroke-box and the function path() are not yet implented in most of the browsers.

Comment: thank you very much, i am with you